# powershell write-debug blank line

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to get Write-Debug to print a blank line without printing DEBUG:
Ex:

Write-Debug `n

Write-Debug `n # additional parameters or command here

Write-Debug `n

Output :>

DEBUG:

DEBUG:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this by creating function `Write-Debug` like this:

```
PS> function Write-Debug {
  [cmdletbinding()]
  param($message)
  if (!$message) { 
    write-host; return 
  }
  $cmd = get-command -commandType cmdlet Write-Debug
  & $cmd $message
}

PS> Write-Debug 'this is test'; Write-Debug; Write-Debug '3rd row'
DEBUG: this is test

DEBUG: 3rd row
```

If you create new function with the same name as a cmdlet, you hide the original cmdlet, because PowerShell will first try to find function with name `Write-Debug`. If there is none, PowerShell tries to find cmdlet with that name. (generally the first type of command that PowerShell tries to find is alias, not a function).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately not. This "debug:" prefix is controlled by the powershell host, be that powershell.exe or powershell_ise.exe and is not configurable.

**Update**: you could do something dirty like write out some backspaces.

```
write-debug "`b`b`b`b`b`b`b      " -debug
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I wanted something like that.
To improve on it a bit: Just use a single carriage return at the beginning of the line:
```Write-Debug "`rthis is is a debug message"```